# R performance - Fitting models on ~1 million time series

Tags: r, performance, time-series

I am trying to create a workflow that could yield predictions for a time series of sales at a product level, based on past data.

I start with a list of data.tables : the name is the product ID I want to predict quantities for and the contents is a vector of historic quantities, ranging 1/jan/12 to 1/sep/16.

```
> rawlist[1]
```

$`2456057`

```
      Qty
   1:   1
   2:   1
   3:   1
   4:   1
   5:   1
  ---    
1701:   1
1702:   1
1703:   1
1704:   1
1705:   1
```

I've set up  a foreach () %dopar% construct in order to speed things up, inside which I convert the vector into a time series and fit a STLF model on it. I append the product data (object name in the list) as well as the prediction dates to create a data.table of predictions for each product.

**My question** : I am trying to scale this to run for ~ 1 million products. I am currently testing this out on 1000 products in ~ 1.1 minutes, 10.000 products in ~ 13 minutes.

I've already optimized the first split into products and the union (rbind) at the end, but have trouble improving the %dopar% part - think there should be something more to it. Any idea appreciated! Thanks

Profiling for the loop:

```
    > summaryRprof(tmp[[13]])
$by.self
             self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
".Call"           0.12     75.0       0.12      75.0
"NextMethod"      0.02     12.5       0.02      12.5
"seq.int"         0.02     12.5       0.02      12.5

$by.total
                   total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"data.table"             0.16     100.0      0.00      0.0
"ets"                    0.16     100.0      0.00      0.0
"etsmodel"               0.16     100.0      0.00      0.0
"forecast"               0.16     100.0      0.00      0.0
"forecast.stl"           0.16     100.0      0.00      0.0
"forecastfunction"       0.16     100.0      0.00      0.0
"stlf"                   0.16     100.0      0.00      0.0
".Call"                  0.12      75.0      0.12     75.0
".cbind.ts"              0.04      25.0      0.00      0.0
"as.ts"                  0.04      25.0      0.00      0.0
"Ops.ts"                 0.04      25.0      0.00      0.0
"window"                 0.04      25.0      0.00      0.0
"window.default"         0.04      25.0      0.00      0.0
"window.ts"              0.04      25.0      0.00      0.0
"NextMethod"             0.02      12.5      0.02     12.5
"seq.int"                0.02      12.5      0.02     12.5

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 0.16
```

Full code below:

```
horizon = 14

raw2 = data.table(raw)

rawlist = raw2[, list(list(.SD)), by=Ordered_Product_Key]$V1

setattr(rawlist, 'names', unique(raw2$Ordered_Product_Key))


dates = seq(from = as.Date(as.character(max(raw$Date_Key)),format='%Y%m%d')+1, to = as.Date(as.character(max(raw$Date_Key)),format='%Y%m%d')+horizon, by=1)


s3 = Sys.time()

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

cl<-makeCluster(no_cores)

registerDoParallel(cl)


bulkdata = foreach(i=rawlist, x=names(rawlist), .packages=c('forecast','data.table')) %dopar% {  

 data.table(Product = x, Dates = dates  , Forecast = forecast(stlf(ts( i$Qty   , frequency = 365, start=2012)),h=horizon)$mean )

}

stopCluster(cl)


s4 = Sys.time()

df = do.call(rbind,bulkdata)
```

Comment: Have you profiled the code inside the loop?

Comment: @Roland I've updated my post with profiling info for the loop. Thanks

Comment: I didn't write "profile the loop". I wrote "profile[d] the code **inside** the loop". You only see there what `foreach` does and not what happens on the parallel workers (which is the interesting part).

Comment: @Roland Thanks. How should I profile the code inside the loop? Isn't the Rprof() object rewritten every iteration?

R crashed when I run the following.



`bulkdata = foreach(i=rawlist, x=names(rawlist), .packages=c('forecast','data.table')) %dopar% {  
  
 Rprof(tmp <- tempfile())  
  
 data.table(Product = x, Dates = dates  , Forecast = forecast(stlf(ts( i$Qty   , frequency = 365, start=2012)),h=horizon)$mean )
 
 Rprof()
 
}
`

Comment: Simply do not run the `foreach` loop. Create an example of `i` and `x` and run the code repeatedly in a simple `for` loop, e.g., `for (k in 1:1e3)  data.table(Product = x, Dates = dates  , Forecast = forecast(stlf(ts( i$Qty   , frequency = 365, start=2012)),h=horizon)$mean )`.

Comment: @Roland Thanks again.  I've set up profiling using the following code. Results vary from iteration to iteration - see post.

`
tmp = list()


for (x in seq_along(rawlist) )
{
 Rprof(tmp[[x]] <- tempfile())  
 
 data.table(Product = names(rawlist[[x]]), Dates = dates  , Forecast = forecast(stlf(ts( rawlist[[x]]$Qty   , frequency = 365, start=2012)),h=horizon)$mean )
  
 Rprof()
}

`

Comment: No, you should not do this for all elements of `rawlist`, but repeatedly for one of its elements: `Rprof(); for (i in 1:100)   data.table(Product = names(rawlist[[1]]), Dates = dates , Forecast = forecast(stlf(ts( rawlist[[1]]$Qty , frequency = 365, start=2012)),h=horizon)$mean ); Rprof(NULL)`. Anyway, I suspect you can't improve this easily (without rewriting the functions or without using a different algorithm).

Comment: Hi! I am interested if you finally suceed to optimize the code as I see now answer so far and I am struggling with almost the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, also @Sven, I am wondering the same. I want to forecast also a million time series in this way. So any of you have optimized examples?